# is there way to truncate string upto certain characters without ending in between words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some code in `java` to truncate certain string upto certain chracters , but not in between the words. Here is code which one I am using in java

```
public static String truncateTo(String originalText, int len) {
    if (originalText.length() > len) {
        if (originalText.charAt(len) != ' ') {
            for (int x=len-1;x>=0;x--) {
                if (Character.isWhitespace(originalText.charAt(x))) {
                    return originalText.substring(0, x);
                }
            }
        }
        // default if none of the conditions are met
        return originalText.substring(0, len);
    }
    return originalText;
}
```

I am having requirement of same stuff to do in `javascript`.
tried so far

```
if ($('#notificationData').html().length > 60) {
    if ($('#notificationData').html().charAt(60) != ' ') {
        for (var x=60-1;x>=0;x--) {
            if ($('#notificationData').html().charAt(x)) {
                    return $('#notificationData').html().substring(0, x);
            }
        }
    }
      // default if none of the conditions are met
    console.log( $('#notificationData').html().substring(0, len));
}
```

Comment: still there is problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on

```
if ($('#notificationData').html().charAt(x)) {
```

You don't check for the whitespace

Below the correct (and refactored) code

```
function truncateTo(originalText, len) {

    if (originalText.length > len) {
        if (originalText[len] != ' ') {
            for (var x = len-1; x >= 0; x--) {
                if (originalText[x] == ' ') {
                    return originalText.substring(0, x);
                }
            }
        }

        return originalText.substring(0, len);
    }

    return originalText;
}
```